# vb.net Creating folders for each files in the listbox

Tags: vb.net

listbox1 lists sub-folders that contain files.

listbox2 has files list.

When button1 is pressed I hope the folders are made for each files in the listbox2(folder name should be as same as file name) and then move corresponding file to that directory.

```
eg) 
listbox1
d:\data\sub1\
listbox2
d:\data\sub1\a.7z
d:\data\sub1\ab.7z

when button1 is pushed

we can find the files in...

d:\data\sub1\a\a.7z
d:\data\sub1\ab\a.7z
```

I'm having trouble to make it. I know how to list files in the listbox but I don't know how to deal with each of them.

Also, if I try to get rid of 7z extension in the directory name with the following code, it says it can not be used for the listbox.

```
   If folderslist.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            ' selected item is filepath
            Dim filePath = folderslist.SelectedItem.ToString

         The string you are searching

         Dim s As String = filePath

     Find index of uppercase letter 'B'
          Dim i As String = 0
          Dim j As String = s.IndexOf("."c)


     This new string contains the substring starting at B
       part = s.Substring(i, j - i + 1)

         If (s.IndexOf(".") = -1) Then
    part = "Not found"

       End If
```

Any advice, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to manually split the path to get separate strings. Use

- `System.IO.Path.GetFileName`, and
- `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and
- `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`.

And the like.

It's a little difficult to give a direct, explicit example, because it's quite unclear what you want to do based on what you're shown. But as *an* example...

```
Dim basePath as String = "d:\data\sub1\"
Dim fullName as String = folderslist.SelectedItem.ToString()
Dim fileName as String = Path.GetFileName(fullName)
Dim partialName as String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullName)

Dim newPath as String = Path.Combine(basePath, partialName)
newPath = newPath + Path.Combine(newPath, fileName)
```

Comment: Thank you. GetFileNameWithoutExtension is a good advice. However my main question is how do I make a folder with the file names in the listbox.(there are 500 subfolders with 10 to 20 files each) I want to make folders for each file and move the file in there.(I just need to sort it that way)

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't write it clearly. Its actually two questions. First one is about how to do something for each items in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

 If folderslist.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then

  Dim filePath = folderslist.SelectedItem.ToString

            fileslist.Items.Clear()


            Dim dirf As String() = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.7z")

            Dim dira As String
            For Each dira In dirf

                fileslist.Items.Add(dira)
            Next


            If mkfold = 1 Then

                For Each dira In dirf

                    Dim pName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dira)


                    Dim strDir As String
                    strDir = filePath & "\" & pName

                    If DirExists(Trim(strDir)) = False Then
                        MkDir(Trim(strDir))
                    End If


                    Dim f_name As String = Path.GetFileName(dira)
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(dira, strDir & "\" & f_name)
                    Next

               mkfold = 0

            End If

        End If

 Private Sub mkfol_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mkfol.Click
        mkfold = 1


    End Sub
```

Somehow I got what I wanted.